# Pass array of integer as parameter to the url of an Ajax call

Tags: ajax, api, asp.net-mvc-5

I know this has been asked multiple times, but unfortunately it's still unclear to me. How do I pass array of integer as parameter to the url of an Ajax call? I need the elements of the array to show in the url.

This is inside script tags in the View :

```
function DeleteRoom(id, IDarray) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/Room/DeleteRoom?RoomId=" + id + "&userDevicesId="+ IDarray,
        type: "DELETE",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: IDarray, //data that will be passed to the array (?)
        traditional: true, //if I get it right, this serializes the array
        success: function (data) {
        ... }
    });
}
```

This is the API

```
public void DeleteRoom (int id, [FromUri] int[] IDarray)
```

This only reads the first element in the array from database, and so it deletes only the first element. It's like I'm passing `Int`! Then the browser crashes (stop script) and I get this error

> DELETE .../api/Room/RemoveRoomWithDevices?RoomId=2392&userDevicesId=1549
>
> 204 No Content   62ms
>
> XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal

Is the url syntax wrong? Or else, is there suggestions to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **JSON.stringify()**

here is your url

```
url: "/api/Room/DeleteRoom?RoomId=" + id + "&userDevicesId="+ JSON.stringify(IDarray)
```

Btw why you are using again a data attribute in ajax call..? Since you have included data array in the url.

Comment: I need this to work so I'm trying multiple things :( I just tried JSON.stringify() + deleted the data attribute, and still get the same error.

Comment: I think in DeleteRoom (int id, [FromUri] int[] IDarray) method you should give string type for IDarray param not int type. Since parameters from request are string type.

Comment: I can't. Its type in the database is Int. This creates another error